# Two-Dimensional Grid Join in T-SQL? Row-to-Row correlation within a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, datagrid

I'm honestly not sure what to call this, and I feel like I may be missing something really basic, but I've been scouring the internet all day and have been unable to find a simple or straightforward T-SQL operation to do what I am looking for.

I am building a database with tournament match data, and I want to show player matchups (total wins/losses) between any two players in a large grid. So for example, if I have this combined temp table:

```
Player1 wins losses Player2
A       4    2      B
A       1    3      C
B       2    4      A
B       0    5      C
C       3    1      A
C       5    0      B
```

I want to find a way to get these results in a grid, something like this:

```
      A     B     C
A     0/0   4/2   1/3
B     2/4   0/0   0/5
C     3/1   5/0   0/0
```

Of course, this is a super simplified example. In reality there may be dozens or even hundreds of players. It needs to be able to work seamlessly no matter how many players there are. I will be running this from a report-style procedure to analyze the data, in a format that could be copy/pasted into excel for example.

I'm sure I could do something like this with some really complex dynamic SQL, but I was hoping there was a better / more standard way to build a query of this fashion.

I have a feeling I may have even learned how to do this many years ago in college but have since forgotten.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **EDIT 2 - Source Will Be A Temp Table and Player1 will be All Inclusive**

**Example**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
 From (
        Select XAxis=A.Player
              ,YAxis=B.Player
              ,Value=''0/0''
         From (Select Distinct Player=Player1 From #YourTemp) A
         Join (Select Distinct Player=Player1 From #YourTemp) B on 1=1
         Union All
         Select Player1
               ,Player2
               ,Value=concat(wins,''/'',losses) 
          From #YourTemp
      ) A
 Pivot (max([Value]) For [XAxis] in (' + Stuff((Select Distinct ','+QuoteName(Player1) From #YourTemp Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'')  + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
--Print @SQL
```

**Returns**

[image]

**If it Helps with the Visualization** the subquery **"feeding"** the Pivot looks like this:

[image]

> **Now, If the Source Temp Contains ALL Combinations**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
 From (
         Select XAxis=Player1
               ,YAxis=Player2
               ,Value=concat(wins,''/'',losses) 
          From #YourTemp
      ) A
 Pivot (max([Value]) For [XAxis] in (' + Stuff((Select Distinct ','+QuoteName(Player1) From #YourTemp Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'')  + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
--Print @SQL
```

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid I would have to go this route. Certainly seems odd that there is no existing SQL syntax to handle this type of query, as it seems like it would come up fairly often. But I guess that's what some of the higher level database languages are for.

Comment: I will leave this open for now, in case someone is able to provide a simpler solution.

Comment: @TimLeaf As you know, SQL Server is declarative by design.  It does not support macro-substition (like say ... Visual FoxPro).  I'll noodle it a bit more and see if I can "tighten the screws"  This would be a simple dynamic pivot, the only trick was to make both axis square.

Comment: @TimLeaf Just curious,  would a distinct list of Player1 be a comprehensive list of players, or do we have get a combined/distinct list list of Player1 and Player2 ?

Comment: Basically I will be running this from a procedure, with a customized list of players, and will be starting by creating a temp table that has the "feeding" data as you suggested. For this usage, I will probably be requiring that the list of Player1 and Player2 names are identical (and can fill in any empty records or zeroes if needed when there are no results). Anything that could make this simpler to implement I am willing to try. This is likely the first of many such queries I will be utilizing for this project.